# Determining whether a set is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently trying to determine whether the following set is linearly independent: 
$u=(4,3,-2), v=(2,-6,7), w=(14,-12,17)$
It can be easily observed that $w=2u+3v$ and since w can be expressed in terms of $u$ and $v$, I have concluded that the set is not linearly independent. However, according to the solution to the question, it is linearly independent. This has induced me to question the basic definition of linear independence.

If one element of a set can be expressed in terms of the other elements of the same set, does that not automatically mean that the vectors depend on each other and,therefore, linearly dependent?

Edit: Here is the answer provided in the memo:

We set $au + bv + cw = a(4, 3, −2) + b(2, −6, 7) + c(14, −12, 17) = (0, 0, 0)$
which is equivalent to the matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -2 & -6 \\
    2 & 1 & 7 \\
    -2 & 7 & 17 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}1 \\b \\c \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\0 \\0 \\   \end{bmatrix}
$

With a little Gauss elimination we see that $a = b = c = 0$is the only solution of this system of linear equations, so the vectors ${u, v, w}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: The book is in error...

Comment: Yes you are correct, $w=2u+3v$ implies they are not independent.  I checked your math and it is true that $w=2u+3v$.  So maybe the answer is wrong or you copied the problem wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$3$ vectors are, and only are linearly independent, if only $0u+0v+0w=0$(null vector) stands, and you can't make the null vector from any of their other combinations. Since $2u+3v-w=(8,6,-4)+(6,-18,21)-(14,-12,17)=(0,0,0)$, they are linearly dependent. Your approach is totally correct, your book must be false.

Comment: I edited the post with the solution provided. Could you please tell me why the solution is incorrect?